# What kind of threshold can I use on concrete?

Tags: pocket-door, vinyl-flooring, threshold

I just laid some vinyl planking throughout most of my house and there are a few places where I don't know what kind of threshold to use.

[image]

Here I have a rock floor meeting the vinyl planking underneath a pocket door. All of the thresholds I saw need to be screwed into place and have a higher profile than I would like. While I could trim the door, I also have a special needs son that drags his feet and could trip on much of a profile.

Is there a threshold that could keep the end of the flooring from being kicked and torn up without being screwed down or creating  a big profile?

Comment: What about just filling the gap with colored grout?

Comment: I would use caulk before grout.  OP, when you say concrete, what do you mean?  This looks like a slate floor.  is there a level difference between the "rock" and vinyl?

Comment: Yes, there is a level difference. The far side is about 1/4", while the close side is about 1/8". By concrete I meant the grout between the slate. Caulk sounds like a good idea, Do you have a specific kind in mind that you could leave as an answer?